# Integrating a function which uses substitutions

Tags: python-2.7, integration, substitution

Hello experienced Pythoners

My question regards a simple triple integration in Python. A simple example of the function to be integrated is the following:

```
-2*u - 5*v + 9*w + 15
```

These functions are read in from an input file, but firstly I wanted to check the time by simply placing this as the function. This function is integrated over u,v and w from 0 -> 1. The following code will integrate this function:

```
from scipy.integrate import tplquad
from time import time as epochTime

def ppsi(u,v,w):
   F = -2*u - 5*v + 9*w + 15
   return F
start = epochTime()
func = lambda u,v,w: ppsi(u,v,w)
u1,u2 = 0, 1
v1,v2 = lambda u: 0, lambda u: 1
w1,w2 = lambda u,v: 0, lambda u,v: 1
test = tplquad(ppsi, u1, u2, v1, v2, w1, w2)
print test
print ('Took:{:.3}s'.format(epochTime() - start))
```

This is evaulated very quickly as one would expect ( < 0.01s). As these functions are actually being read in from an input file I first replace the string characters with a usable format Python can use:

```
from scipy.integrate import tplquad
from time import time as epochTime

def ppsi(u,v,w):
    ## Psi is the function read in from the input file
    f = sympy.sympify(Psi)
    f = f.subs({"u": u})
    f = f.subs({"v": v})
    f = f.subs({"w": w})
    return f
start = epochTime()
func = lambda u,v,w: ppsi(u,v,w)
u1,u2 = 0, 1
v1,v2 = lambda u: 0, lambda u: 1
w1,w2 = lambda u,v: 0, lambda u,v: 1
test = tplquad(func, u1, u2, v1, v2, w1, w2)
print test
print ('Took:{:.3}s'.format(epochTime() - start))
```

The replace commands allow Python to process the function as the one listed above and both snippets of code give the same answer, but the second one takes considerably longer to evaluate ( > 8s).

Is this time increase due to the function applying the substitutions every time the integration is run through? Is there a simple way to remedy this and decrease the evaluation time in the second instance?

Thank you in advance

Comment: how about checking the Psi function for how much time it takes?Is the input file large or has just the single function mentioned above?Also .subs is slow.

Comment: check out this [link](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/numeric-computation.html). You can see the comparisons between various expression substitution methods.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. The example given above is a very small function but they can be much larger. That link is interesting, I never knew there was such a performance issue with .subs.

Answer (score 0):

Using the link that wolfsgang provided I modified the code and there was a dramatic speed increase:

```
start = epochTime()
f = lambdify([u,v,w], Psi, "numpy")
u1,u2 = 0, 1
v1,v2 = lambda u: 0, lambda u: 1
w1,w2 = lambda u,v: 0, lambda u,v: 1
F = tplquad(f, u1,u2,v1,v2,w1,w2)
print F
print ('Took:{:.3}s'.format(epochTime() - start))
```

This took 0.0095s to evaluate vs. the 8 seconds it originally took. So a performance increase of three orders of magnitude. Lambdify is certainly the way to go!